# Generate mutant for python program

Tags: python, mutation-testing

Existing mutation testing tools for python like Cosmic Ray or Mutpy seem not to store generated mutants. I want to find a tool which can generate and **store** the mutants for python program because I need the mutants. Does this kind of tool exist?

Comment: I also need this. I don't want to use mutmut as a testing tool. I simply want to generate a load of mutants into files and look at them. Couldn't see any combo of the options which works for this.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "store". Mutmut (https://github.com/boxed/mutmut/) can generate diffs for the mutants and it keeps a little database of the mutants and their status.